# ASP.Net Web Forms tutorial has mistake --- how to troubleshoot

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am following ASP.NET Web forms tutorial at

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/shopping-cart

ProductContext defines two tables, Categories and Products

using System.Data.Entity;

```
namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProductContext()
            : base("WingtipToys")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which is reflected here, circled in red

[image]

However if I follow the tutorial modify the code

[image]

And then build the project, the table ShoppingCartItems does NOT appear

[image]

And when I press F5 to debug the project I get the following error

[image]

How to troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you tried commenting to the author of the tutorial / article?

Comment: @CodeX Yes, I have, still waiting for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Glowie, since your database structure changes due to adding the ShoppingCartItems, you need to enable and run the EntityFramework migrations as per the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx). You are right, the tutorial is missing this step, hence the reason you are getting an error